# Loop a variable in Terraform for key vaults

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am having an issue to upload multiple secrets (10) to multiple vaults (2)... The code works but when I try to upload the secrets, only the last secret is being uploaded to each vault.

I've tried to use the secrets in a different variable, but had the same issue.

Here is my code:

```
# Create a new resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg_test" {
  for_each = var.key_vaults

  name     = each.key
  location = each.value["location"]
}

# Pull data from current client
data "azurerm_client_config" "current_user" {}

# Create the Azure Key Vault
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "test_vault" {
  for_each = var.key_vaults

  name                       = each.value["vault_name"]
  location                   = each.value["location"]
  resource_group_name        = each.key
  purge_protection_enabled   = false
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

  enabled_for_deployment          = var.enabled_for_deployment
  enabled_for_disk_encryption     = var.enabled_for_disk_encryption
  enabled_for_template_deployment = var.enabled_for_template_deployment
  enable_rbac_authorization       = var.enable_rbac_authorization
  public_network_access_enabled   = var.public_network_access_enabled

  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current_user.tenant_id
  sku_name  = each.value["sku_name"]
  tags      = each.value["tags"]

  network_acls {
    default_action = "Allow"
    bypass         = "AzureServices"
  }
}

# Create a Default Azure Key Vault access policy with Admin permissions
# This policy must be kept for a proper run of the "destroy" process
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "default_admin_policy" {
  for_each = var.key_vaults

  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.test_vault[each.key].id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current_user.tenant_id
  object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current_user.object_id

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  key_permissions         = var.kv-key-permissions-full
  secret_permissions      = var.kv-secret-permissions-full
  certificate_permissions = var.kv-certificate-permissions-full
  storage_permissions     = var.kv-storage-permissions-full
}

# Create an Azure Key Vault secrets
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  for_each = var.key_vaults

  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.test_vault[each.key].id
  name         = lookup(each.value, "name")
  value        = lookup(each.value, "value") 
  content_type = lookup(each.value, "content_type")
}
```

Here is my variable:

```
variable "key_vaults" {
  type = map(object({
    vault_name = string
    location   = string
    sku_name   = string
    tags       = map(string)

    secrets = map(object({
    name         = string
    value        = string
    content_type = string
  }))
  }))
}
```

Thanks for the helping this terraform apprentice.

Comment: I don't believe that the lookup() function will traverse into child objects like that. I think it is scoped to only one map.

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: Hey Marcin! The code won't loop through the secrets... it will upload only one secret (the last one on tfvars).

Answer (score 2):

Check the following code:

Here I have looped through secrets .

**main.tf**

```
locals {
  key_vaults = {
    "kakey_vault_1" = {
      name = "kakeyvault1"
    
    },
    "kakey_vault_2" = {
      name = "kakeyvault2"
      
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "key_vault" {
  for_each = local.key_vaults
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
   object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
    
    certificate_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "DeleteIssuers",
      "Get",
      "GetIssuers",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "ListIssuers",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "Purge",
      "SetIssuers",
      "Update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Create",
      "Decrypt",
      "Delete",
      "Encrypt",
      "Get",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Sign",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "Update",
      "Verify",
      "WrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Set",
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      "Get","Set"
    ]
  
}
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kvsecrettest" {
  count = length(var.secret_maps)
  name         = keys(var.secret_maps)[count.index]
  value        = values(var.secret_maps)[count.index]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault["kakey_vault_1"].id
}
```

**Variables.tf:**

```
variable "secret_maps" {
    type = map(string)
    default = {
        "name1"= "value1"
        "name2" = "value2"
        "name3" = "value3"
    }

 }



resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kvsecrettest" {
  count = length(var.secret_maps)
  name         = keys(var.secret_maps)[count.index]
  value        = values(var.secret_maps)[count.index]
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault["kakey_vault_2"].id
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello kavyaS, thanks for the help! I can try to use your code and modify a bit to fir multiple resource groups.